# Web2py 3rd party authentication

Tags: python-2.7, janrain, pythonanywhere

I have made a webapp in python using web2py which has 3rd party authentication using Janrain as recommended.
On my local server it worked absolutely fine, but now when I deployed on [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com), the authentication is giving me the following error

"class 'urllib2.URLError' urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden"

Stack

===========

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1222, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden>
```

==========================

For third party authentication I had used yahoomail id.

Comment: possible duplicate of [open url from pythonanywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597390/open-url-from-pythonanywhere)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has now been fixed, but in case anyone else comes across this issue or a similar issue:

the problem was that free users on PythonAnywhere have restricted internet, that goes via a proxy and only allows a [whitelist of sites](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/).

The sites `.janrain.com` and `.rpxnow.com` weren't on the whitelist at the time, but we have now added them, and the janrain/yahoo mail login now works.

So, for anyone else that happens to be going via a proxy and trying to use this service, those are the sites you need to add.  (may also be of interest to paranoid people that like to run noscript, if you find some federated auth system failing, you may need to unblock rpxnow).

Happy coding everyone!